# Converting nested ArrayList into List Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this method

```
public List<List<Stat>> ConvertReportCases (ArrayList<ArrayList<Stat>> stats)
```

It is an interface implementation where the return type is a `List<List<Stat>>`. In general how do I convert from a nested ArrayList to List in Java?

Thanks

**Edit**
Thanks for the suggestions I could make my parameter passed as List but then it would be wrong since the caller will have to pass it as List, whereas in my particular case I could have different versions (polymorphism) to check this issue.

Comment: An `ArrayList` already implements the `List` interface, i don't see your point there?

Comment: And I actually don't understand, why you have `ArrayList`s in the first place. You should always work with `List`s (which are one of the implementations of the `List` interface, like `ArrayList`). So you can create your list like this: `List<Stat> list = new ArrayList<Stat>();`

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue Perhaps he needs to pass it to a method that only accepts a List<List<Stat>>?

Comment: @brimborium ArrayList adds new methods. It makes sense to use an ArrayList if you want to use some of those methods.

Comment: @Pablo I see, very good point. I never used the different implementations for their additional methods, but just for their different implementation (and thus runtime performance/memory usage).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Really, there is no converting needed.

If you can't touch the declaration of the list, you should change the method signature to this. It uses [wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html).

```
public List<? extends List<Stat>> convertReportCases(List<? extends List<Stat>> stats);
```

---

However, the most clean way would be to change the method signature to

```
public List<List<Stat>> convertReportCases(List<List<Stat>> stats);
```

And declare the list as

```
List<List<Stat>> list = new ArrayList<List<Stat>>();
for (List<Stat> sublist : list) {
    sublist = new ArrayList<Stat>();
}
```

If you use `List` methods, you will be ok, there will be no converting needed. And since `ArrayList` is-a `List` and is practically only useful for its `List` methods, you should be ok!

Comment: Notice the  small letter in the beginning of `convertReportCases()`. [It's Java's convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) [to name methods this way.](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm)

Comment: Is the concept of interfaces and implementing classes in Java clear to you, or should we provide some more resources?

Comment: Yup this should do, thanks very much for the suggestions. I learnt a new thing today !

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<List<Stat>> ConvertReportCases (ArrayList<ArrayList<Stat>> stats) {
   List<List<Stat>> newList = new ArrayList<List<Stat>>(stats.size());
   for (ArrayList<Stat> arrayList : stats) {
      newList.add(arrayList);
   }
   return newList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through the fist list and convert each list. Something like:

```
public List<List<Stat>> ConvertReportCases (ArrayList<ArrayList<Stat>> stats) {
    List<List<Stat>> list = new ArrayList<List<Stat>>();
    for (List<Stat> l : stats) {
        list.add(l);
    }
    return list;
}
```

The problem appears because of generic covariance. You can find more [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html).