# How to convert list having sub-List into single Array-list

Tags: java

I have a List something like this:

```
List<String> name = [[tom,john,peter,richered][manoj,satya,sachin,andrew]]
```

How would I convert it into a single ArrayList, using stream

Comment: Possible Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910312/converting-nested-arraylist-into-list-java

Comment: Downvote for posting non-compiling sample code without specifying input and output and then complaining the answers do not fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) in Java8,

```
List<List<String>> main = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> l1 = Arrays.asList("1", "2");
List<String> l2 = Arrays.asList("3", "4");
main.add(l1);
main.add(l2);
List<String> ans = main.stream()
                       .flatMap(list -> list.stream())
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(ans);
```

<sub>**OUTPUT**</sub>

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: In case if you don't know the input that you are entering asList, how would you achieve this output.

Comment: This is just to prepare lists quickly for example. Notice the important part where list of list is processed to get list named `ans`.

Comment: ans is absolutely fine, but its not relevant to my code:  consider this again [[tom,john,peter,richered][manoj,satya,sachin,andrew]]   here I can separate these lists into sublist but I would not be use subList in the code provided by you.

Comment: Okay. Can you add more code or explanation to your question, please? It'll be really helpful to track down the exact problem.

Comment: and yes I don't want to enter subList value manually in asList() in the code because it will be dynamic in future

Comment: main.add(l1); here l1 is a list but add() takes only String args, so its another flaw in the code.

Comment: The code I've shared is working fine. I think the input list you provided is misleading. I guess you don't have list of list you only have list of string and you logically decided the sub lists inside that list. is it so?

Comment: Alright, your code is absolute fine, earlier I was using substrings and when I was adding them to the array list using add(subString), it was giving me compile time error, now I realize I don't have to use substrings I only need to use the stream one code.  My Apology and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `flatMap`:

```
List<List<String>> name = Lists.newArrayList(Lists.newArrayList("a", "b", "c", "d"), Lists.newArrayList("e", "f", "g"));

List<String> namesTogether = name.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(namesTogether);
```

> [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]

Comment: Answer is not relevant to my question, please consider other comments

Comment: @SanatSingh No, I will not "consider other comments", this is the exact answer to your question. This (in the same way as the other answer) *"converts a list having sub-lists into a single list using java 8 streams"*.

Comment: Alright, your code is absolute fine, earlier I was using substrings and when I was adding them to the array list using add(subString), it was giving me compile time error, now I realize I don't have to use substrings I only need to use the stream one code. please accept my apology and thanks for your help.